# Include a Bash script within a Bash Script with parameters

Tags: bash

I am trying to work out how to create a bash script to run the following script with parameters.  The command works fine when entering it into the terminal manually.

```
./rackspace-cloudfiles.sh -x PUT -c CONTAINER /path/to/file.zip
```

I have searched and studied this for hours, and I cant make head nor tail of the endless number of examples, the only thing I can come up with is that I am clearly out of my depth, as I thought this would be such a simple script to make but seems not.  The easiest one I could come up with is this;

```
#!/bin/bash
ARG1="-x PUT"
ARG2="-c CONTAINER"
ARG3="/path/to/file.zip"
./rackspace-cloudfiles.sh "$ARG1" "$ARG2" "$ARG3"
```

but that results in an error 'ERROR: Invalid request is specified"
I really have no idea.

Credit for the included script: 
http://www.gyrocode.com/articles/upload-to-rackspace-cloud-files-using-a-shell-script/

Comment: `-c CONTAINER` is *two* arguments.

Comment: To expand on rici's comment. `-c` is the argument flag and `CONTAINER` is its value. They are two arguments to the shell script so you need to pass them as two arguments.

Comment: sorry, I  have just found the solution with some random experimentation, simply remove the " from the variables, despite other examples using them.   ie the last line is simply 
`./rackspace-cloudfiles.sh $ARG1 $ARG2 $ARG3`